# Changing the size of a child widget when zooming with the wheel of the parent widget

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I have a parent widget(QWidget). I draw a mesh on it using the paintEvent method. This widget has a child widget (QWidget). The child widget can only move through the grid cells of the parent widget (I have already overridden these methods). I need to implement the following functionality:

Ability to scale the grid. That is, when I scroll the mouse wheel, the number of cells that fit on my screen increases. Accordingly, when I scroll the wheel in the other direction, the amount decreases. I implemented this functionality in the wheelEvent method.

Increase the size of the widget that is located in the cell. That is, as you approach, the size of the widget grows in proportion to the size of the cell. I have problems with this, because the widget size decreases/increases not in proportion to the cell size.
I tried using coordinate transformation, but it didn't work. Let me clarify right away: I dont implemented all this functionality in QGraphicsView. But these classes are not suitable, because it is impossible to place a widget in which a third-party application window is installed on QGraphicsScene. And my program involves intercepting third-party windows and installing these windows into a widget with further adding these widgets to the grid. I would appreciate any help!

```
class MoveWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MoveWidget, self).__init__()
        self.click_rect = self.rect()
        self.selected_edge = None
        self.click_pos = None
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow; "
                           "color: red;"
                           "border: 2px solid blue;")
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        grid.addWidget(QPushButton("fdfdsfdsfdsf"), 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(QPushButton("1111111111111"), 1, 0)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 300)

    def paintEvent(self, a0) -> None:

        opt = QStyleOption()

        opt.initFrom(self)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PrimitiveElement.PE_Widget, opt, painter, self)


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.click_pos = event.pos()
        rect = self.rect()
        top = abs(rect.top())
        bottom = abs(rect.bottom())
        left = abs(rect.left())
        right = abs(rect.right())

        if abs(left - abs(self.click_pos.x())) < 30 and (
                abs(bottom - abs(self.click_pos.y())) > 30) and (abs(top - abs(self.click_pos.y())) > 30):
            self.selected_edge = 'left'

        elif abs(right - abs(self.click_pos.x())) < 30 and (
                abs(bottom - abs(self.click_pos.y())) > 30) and (abs(top - abs(self.click_pos.y())) > 30):
            self.selected_edge = 'right'

        elif abs(top - abs(self.click_pos.y())) < 30 and (abs(right - abs(self.click_pos.x())) > 30) and (
                abs(left - abs(self.click_pos.x())) > 30):
            self.selected_edge = 'top'

        elif abs(bottom - abs(self.click_pos.y())) < 30 and (
                abs(right - abs(self.click_pos.x())) > 30) and (abs(left - abs(self.click_pos.x())) > 30):
            self.selected_edge = 'bottom'

        elif (abs(bottom - abs(self.click_pos.y())) < 30) and (abs(right - abs(self.click_pos.x())) < 30):
            self.selected_edge = 'diag_bottom_right'

        elif (abs(bottom - abs(self.click_pos.y())) < 30) and (abs(left - abs(self.click_pos.x())) < 30):
            self.selected_edge = 'diag_bottom_left'

        elif (abs(top - abs(self.click_pos.y())) < 30) and (abs(right - abs(self.click_pos.x())) < 30):
            self.selected_edge = 'diag_top_right'

        elif (abs(top - abs(self.click_pos.y())) < 30) and (abs(left - abs(self.click_pos.x())) < 30):
            self.selected_edge = 'diag_top_left'

        else:
            self.selected_edge = None
        self.click_pos = event.pos()
        self.click_rect = rect
        self.cl = self.mapFromParent(QPoint(rect.x(), rect.y()))
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.pos()

        x_diff = (round((pos.x() - self.click_pos.x()) / 300) * 300)
        y_diff = (round((pos.y() - self.click_pos.y()) / 300) * 300)

        # Start with the rectangle as it was when clicked.
        rect = QRectF(self.click_rect)

        # c = self.rect().getCoords()
        # rect = QRectF(c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3],)
        self.pos()

        if self.selected_edge is None:

            self.move(self.mapToParent(QPoint(x_diff, y_diff)))
            print(self.pos())
            return
        elif self.selected_edge == 'top':
            rect.adjust(0, y_diff, 0, 0)


        elif self.selected_edge == 'left':

            rect.adjust(x_diff, 0, 0, 0)

        elif self.selected_edge == 'bottom':

            rect.adjust(0, 0, 0, y_diff)

        elif self.selected_edge == 'right':

            rect.adjust(0, 0, (x_diff), 0)

        elif self.selected_edge == 'diag_bottom_right':

            rect.adjust(0, 0, (x_diff), (x_diff))

        elif self.selected_edge == 'diag_top_right':

            rect.adjust(0, -(x_diff), (x_diff), 0)

        elif self.selected_edge == 'diag_bottom_left':

            rect.adjust((x_diff), 0, 0, -(x_diff))

        elif self.selected_edge == 'diag_top_left':

            rect.adjust((x_diff), (x_diff), 0, 0)

        s = self.mapToParent(QPoint(int(rect.x()), int(rect.y())))

        d = rect.getCoords()
        ee = self.mapToParent(QPoint(int(d[2]), int(d[3])))
        self.setGeometry(s.x(), s.y(), int(d[2]), int(d[3]))
        s = self.rect()

        print(self.pos())



      
    class WidMain(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet("background: transparent;")
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.movewid = MoveWidget()
        self.movewid.setParent(self)
      
        self.factor = 1.0
   

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        self.factor *= 1.01 ** (event.angleDelta().y() / 15.0)
        self.update()
        print("масштаб", self.factor)
        child = self.children()
        print(child[0].rect(), "геометрия дочернего виджета без применения преобразования в своих координатах")

        transform = QTransform()
        transform.scale(self.factor, self.factor)


        print(transform.mapRect(child[0].rect()), "геометрия дочернего виджета с применения преобразования в своих координатах")
        child[0].setGeometry(transform.mapRect(child[0].rect()))
        print(child[0].rect(),'Новая геометрия дочернего виджета после преобразований')
        transform.reset()
       

    def paintEvent(self, a0) -> None:
        opt = QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PrimitiveElement.PE_Widget, opt, painter, self)

        pen = QPen(QColor("blue"))
        pen.setWidth(5)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        child = self.children()
       
        transform = QTransform()
        transform.scale(self.factor, self.factor)
        painter.setTransform(transform)


        for i in range(0, int(self.width()*1000), 300):
            painter.drawLine(i, 0, i, int(self.height()*1000))
        for i in range(0, int(self.height()*1000), 300):
            painter.drawLine(0, i, int(self.width()*1000), i)

        super().paintEvent(a0)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = WidMain()

    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not considering the *current* scale you previously applied to the geometry.

A possible more correct implementation would be the following:

```py
    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        old = self.factor

        self.factor *= 1.01 ** (event.angleDelta().y() / 15.0)

        child = self.children()

        new = self.factor / old
        transform = QTransform().scale(new, new)

        child[0].setGeometry(transform.mapRect(child[0].rect()))

        self.update()
```

Note, though, that you're using integer based geometries, meaning that if you go beyond a certain "zoom in" factor, you will get approximation issues.

A better approach would be to have a predefined geometry as reference, based on the occupied "cells" of the grid, and always compute new geometries based on that.

Comment: thank you very much, I tried your code and the problem actually occurs when the scaling reaches large factors. The widget geometry changes. I solved this problem as follows. I overridden the sizeHint method, in which I specified the recommended parameters (300x300). And after each call to the wheelevent function, I multiply the scaling factor by the original size.but the problem is that if I try to move the widget to another cell and roll the mouse wheel, then my widget no longer fits into the resized cell

Comment: could you tell me a solution to this problem please?

Comment: @Валентин I cannot, as I don't know how you exactly modified your code, and we cannot answer based on guesses (especially in comments to an unrelated answer). I suggest you to take your time and create a new question with related MRE. Note that for a situation like yours, you may consider letting the parent manage all geometry changes (including resizing of individual items when dragging the edges), possibly using signals or proper event handling.